# What is the red and green price in ebay.com listing?

Tags: ebay

I see sometime the price is in read, sometimes it is in green. What does the color mean?

[image]

Comment: [Relevant](http://community.ebay.com/t5/Search/completed-listing-What-does-the-red-high-lighted-price-mean/qaq-p/8794231)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Listings with a green price are those that were successfully sold. Listing with a red price are items that finished without a sale.

[Source](http://www.salehoo.com/education/ebay-selling/beginners-guide-to-ebay).